# Lazy initialisation and Spring Data DomainClassConverter

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm trying to use the DomainClassConverter from Spring Data to load entities in a controller and then use these entities in a service.

The problem is that I get a LazyInitializationException when I access lazy loaded collection from my Service.

Adding Transactional annotation to the controller does not help, I guess the conversion occurs before the start of the controller transaction.

Is there a way to use this converter in this kind of use case ? can I reattach the entity to the current session someway ?

My controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/quotation-requests/{id}/quotation")
public class QuotationResource {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/lines", method = RequestMethod.POST, params="freeEntry")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<PricingLineDTO> addFreeEntryLine(@PathVariable("id") Quotation quotation, @RequestBody PricingLineDTO pricingLineTo)
    {
        PricingLine pricingLine = conversionService.convert(pricingLineTo, PricingLine.class);

        pricingLine = quotationService.addFreeLineToQuotation(quotation, pricingLine);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(conversionService.convert(pricingLine, PricingLineDTO.class), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

The service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class QuotationService {

    public PricingLine addFreeLineToQuotation(Quotation quotation, PricingLine pricingLine) {
        quotation.getPricingLines().add(pricingLine); // org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: x.y.z.Quotation.pricingLines, could not initialize proxy
    }
}
```

And the entity

```
@Entity
public class Quotation {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<PricingLine> pricingLines = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

If it is not possible, what is my best alternative :

- make the controller transactionnal, inject data repositories in it and still offer a Service API that takes Entities parameters instead of IDs.

Cons: controller become transactional, which seem to be commonly considered as a bad practice; it introduces boilerplate code.

- make the Service API takes IDs as parameters, letting the controller out of the transaction.

Cons: The API become harder to read and can be error prone as every entities as referred as "Long" object, especially when a Service method needs severals entities as input. For example:

```
void addUserToGroup(Long userId, Long groupId)
```

One could easily switch parameters.

Comment: Reattach in your service method before doing any logic. Or add the `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` which keeps the `EntityManager` open for the duration of the request instead of per transaction.

Comment: How do you reattach the entity ? by doing repository.update(entity) ?

Comment: That should do the trick. I would also argue that your method of adding the line is flawed. You should never allow external modification of the collection. Your `getPricingLines` should (imho) return an `ImmutableCollection`. To add you should have a `addPricingLine` line method which takes care of adding the row. And preferably you should remove the `setPricingLines`.

Comment: Ok, good point, thanks for pointing out this mistake.

Comment: OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter works as a charm. I followed your advice on the collection as well, seem more reliable than letting the service handling the association. Thank you.